# local infile with large number of fields

Tags: mysql

I have a text file with a matrix of 4000 X 4000 (rows X columns)
I want to import this into a table

What would be the best approach to do this:

1. load data local infile the full file and then break it into smaller tables
2. First break the text file into chunks with less number of fields and then load data local infile
3. load data local infile the full file and then use this table without modifications

Comment: I think I found the answer to my question.    #1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs. I will have to go with 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my question. #1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs. I will have to go with 2nd option.